# Customized context.xml per environment using maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, context.xml

I have two context.xml files in my Java web project:

context.xml.development
  context.xml.production

and I use maven war plugin to build it.

When I build the project, I'd like maven to copy the proper context.xml to the META-INF directory.

How could I do it? I'm already using profiles in my pom.xml

Answer (score 6):

Another approach (in case you didn't consider it) is to use one context.xml file with place holders. For example:

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/syncDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
           url="${database.url}"/>

</Context>
```

Then, add the war plugin to your maven pom.xml file that has the META-INF folder as a resource that filters:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

That way, you can define these placeholder values as defaults that can be overriden for specific profiles:

```
<properties>
    <database.password>default_user</database.password>
    <database.username>default_password</database.username>
    <database.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.host:1521:defaultsid</database.url>
</properties>

<profiles>  
        <profile>   
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <database.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.host:1521:DEVELOPMENTsid</database.url> 
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what files are used here.  Are the properties (including a password) supposed to go into the pom.xml file?

Comment: If your database URL contains ampersands, you have to escape them twice, once for XML and once for Maven. Like `jdbc:mysql://host:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useTimezone=true...`

Comment: @Marvo Yes, as an example here. Credential management in Maven is another question.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [maven build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and the maven-war-plugin using file filtering to include or exclude the correct files should do the trick.

For example, something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>custom-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>production</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>resources</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>context.xml.development</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>custom-profile2</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>development</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>resources</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>context.xml.production</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then when you run maven be sure to sent the "environment" property appropriately:

`mvn clean install -Denvironment=production`

Comment: This will create a context.xml file (without the .<env> suffix)?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that was needed. Probably the best thing to do would be to put each file in a different directory and name the files "context.xml", then use maven profiles to select the one you want.